# Continuing installing Android packages after pausing Android SDK Manager

Tags: installation, android, sdk

This is my first time doing Android Applications development. My PC is running windows 7 platform. I installed the Android SDK by running the installer_r18-windows.exe from the http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html website. Then the Android SDK Manager runs, i installed all the packages for the Android 4.0.3 (API15) by checking the checkboxes and click install X no of packages[ but not the older Android packages 4.0(API14) and below.] After all the selected android packages are installed completely, I closed the android sdk manager and shut my computer cos i'm too busy.

I intended to install the Android extra packages such as : Android Support, google AdMobs Ads SDK, Google analytics SDK, ...., Google USB driver, Google Web driver.., intel hardware accel Exec manager on the following day. On the following day which is now, i booted windows 7 and i ran the Android SDK Manager. The Android SDK Manager highlighted which packages i did and did not install. I check the checkboxes beside the android extra packages that i mentioned that i wanted to install now.  I clicked install packages. The Android SDK Manager attempted to download the selected packages but failed.

Android SDK Manager log showed one of these messages :

Downloading Google Web Driver Revision 2

File not found...(directory that the package would be installed)

### (Access is denied)

Done. Nothing is installed.

My Question is : 
Why is this so?? How do i continue to install more android packages using the Android SDK Manager??

Answer (score 0):

run sdk manager with "Run as administrator" & it fixes all woes! :)